# Display validation error messages as tooltips?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my asp.net MVC4 application I would like to display my validationmessages as tooltips (when hovering over an image).
Is there any way I could do this? I mean bind the validationmessages to a title in a way?

I can't figure this out myself since the validationmessagefor method returns html tags which obviously cannot be contained in the title.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your ValidationMessages inside a `<div>` tag, and use a tool like the following to show the div content as a tooltip:

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/